# How to call a phtml file in all pages (frontend & backend) using custom magento module?

Tags: phtml, magento2.4

I am using magento 2.4.1
I have created a basic module,
I am trying to call a phtml file in all pages.
I am using `default.xml` file (Separate for each scope)
& calling a phtml file.

But there is some issue in default.xml file.

Can you please post proper code for default.xml for calling phtml in it ?

Thankyou

Comment: you can create seprate phtml for frontend and backend

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this in

**app/code///view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="main.content">
        <block name="my.block" template="<Vendor>_<Module>::myblock.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object"><Vendor>\<Module>\ViewModel\MyBlock</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

But this method implies that you use a view model instead of a block class, which is a better way of rendering something on the frontend.
Also, on line 4 you need to reference a container or block where you want to put your template. You can see a full list of containers and blocks in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Comment: do i need to make default.xml for adminhtml too ?

Comment: I guess i can use same view model as common view model for admin & frontend. is that true ?

Comment: Can you maybe be more specific where in the admin app you want your template to be rendered? I am asking because the answer to your question depends on this. Please elaborate what your module is supposed to do, maybe with an example, and I will be more able to help you.